# How to create JWK from RSA Key pair?

Tags: python, jwt, rsa, jwk

Suppose I have a python structure representing an RSA key pair as follows:

```
rsa_key_pair = {
    'private_key': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAIBADAN__OBSCURED__qxu3sWAlY/bstTB5WfX8PA==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
    'public_key': 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDCDDqGTiBYyoB9T5Haow5gcPBIIiltLVyM4vo8Txia1czgrk2XGH5t4dsWrcXIXjQafNb7PKelXZdRU36vIIAaZCZ0As5LtkC5D93+KO9PFLGkHxWi2G43naR9hOnrKliMjOd+JRUdApdY8c/wYJbDxGGuw7W9e3MsLABFEK+TnPTVJtO8Ix78FiuHRooWfU5ph7clfTeyundN2BNv8mO6ZSBiBAk6tN8Fwpljs96Z/3HnMQutX1/AFkMn5h+E0EV4CgLPvtRazfzoWNlIiXGmiVUVHrM1wna9jT/jyb7aoxkthkAXb6NNyCW/Znxq45Ozy27kZcw/X4WQ0QMmpgfX'
}
```

How can I write python code that will produce the JWK that can be used to verify JWT signed with this RSA private key? The Algorithm used is RSA256.

This website [mkjwk](https://mkjwk.org/) accomplishes what I'm trying to do. But I'm trying to do it in python code.

Comment: I had already looked at that documentation. Where does it show how to generate the JWK fro RSA keys? I don't see it. I only see how to use the JWK to decide, not how to generate it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I midread your question. Here is a related thing: https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwk/api.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [Authlib](https://authlib.org/) to dumps a JWK:

```
from authlib.jose import jwk

jwk.dumps(rsa_key_pair['public_key'], kty='RSA')
jwk.dumps(rsa_key_pair['private_key'], kty='RSA')
```

Here is the result of your public key:

```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "n": "wgw6hk4gWMqAfU-R2qMOYHDwSCIpbS1cjOL6PE8YmtXM4K5Nlxh-beHbFq3FyF40GnzW-zynpV2XUVN-ryCAGmQmdALOS7ZAuQ_d_ijvTxSxpB8VothuN52kfYTp6ypYjIznfiUVHQKXWPHP8GCWw8RhrsO1vXtzLCwARRCvk5z01SbTvCMe_BYrh0aKFn1OaYe3JX03srp3TdgTb_JjumUgYgQJOrTfBcKZY7Pemf9x5zELrV9fwBZDJ-YfhNBFeAoCz77UWs386FjZSIlxpolVFR6zNcJ2vY0_48m-2qMZLYZAF2-jTcglv2Z8auOTs8tu5GXMP1-FkNEDJqYH1w",
  "e": "AQAB"
}
```

via http://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/jose/jwk.html

Comment: For deprecation warnings: https://gist.github.com/lepture/7e38d505c1e22e6e913d8625e5c52cca#jose